# Ordinary Differential Equations with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ be the solution of $y' = y+17$ with $y_1(0)=0$ and $y_2(0)=1$. Then

(a) $y_1$ and $y_2$ will never intersect

(b) $y_1$ and $y_2$ will intersect at $x = 17$

(c) $y_1$ and $y_2$ will intersect at $x = e$

(d) $y_1$ and $y_2$ will intersect at $x = 1$

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Only part (a) is true.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Solve the ODE for each initial condition.
- Analyze the behavior to determine if conditions $(a)$ through $(d)$ apply.

We have:

$$y_1(x) = 17(e^x-1)$$

$$y_2(x) = 18e^x -17$$

Now analyze the conditions to see which is true.

Comment: ODE King strikes again! +1